# Beta function. What is wrong? Misunderstanding.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals, beta-function

I am only interested in real numbers, so here $x,y>0$ real numbers. The Beta function is defined as
$$B(x,y)= \int_0^1 w^{x-1}(1-w)^{y-1}dw.$$

The above integral is defined for every $x,y>0$. Now, take $t>0$ fixed and observe the following:
$$\int_0^t w^{x-1}(t-w)^{y-1}dw = t^{x+y-1} \int_0^1 z^{x-1}(1-z)^{y-1}dw=t^{x+y-1} B(x,y),$$

where I used the change of variables $z=w/t$. Hence,
$$\int_0^t w^{x-1}(t-w)^{y-1}dw = t^{x+y-1} B(x,y).$$

But, now, the above seems weird to me. In principle, $B$ is well-defined and convergent for any $x,y>0$. Nevertheless if, e.g. $x=y=1/4$ then
$$\int_0^t w^{1/4-1}(t-w)^{1/4-1}dw = t^{-1/2} B(1/4,1/4),$$
and hence I get a negative exponent in $t$ which then explodes when $t\to 0$. What is wrong here? :S

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: I don't see the problem if the last integral explodes for small $t$.

Comment: Yes, that would be the only answer I see :) But... if the integrand is in $L^1$ (integrable) shouldn't the whole integral go to 0 when the limits converge to a "zero-measure" set? Like $\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^t w^{-1/2}dw =0$ for example. actually $\lim_{t\to 0} \int_0^t w^{-\alpha}dw =0$ for any $\alpha$ as close to 1 as we want.

Comment: Is there really an issue here? You took $t$ fixed with $t>0$ so your factor $t^{-1/2}$ has a well defined value. Notice that in your limit $t\rightarrow 0$ that the integral used to obtain your identity vanishes and your transform from $z$ to $w$ breaks down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, there is no contradiction.  The issue here is that $t$ appears in the integrand as well as in the upper limit of integration, so as $t \to 0^+$, the minimum value for $0 < x, y < 1$ of $$f(w;t) = w^{x-1} (t-w)^{y-1}$$ increases without bound.  You can see this by setting $x = y = 1/4$ and noting the minimum is attained when $w = t/2$, giving the crude lower bound for the integral as $$\int_{w=0}^t w^{-3/4} (t-w)^{-3/4} \, dw > \frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{t}}.$$  Then as $t \to 0^+$ the divergence is clear.

Geometrically, your thinking is a bit like saying, "if I take a unit square and I perform a sequence of transformations that scales its width by $t$ while scaling its height by $1/t^2$ as $t \to 0^+$, why would the limiting area become infinite?"